# How to increment data to existing data in ROOM UPDATE query

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, insert-update

```
@Query("UPDATE tmcourses SET totalNumberOfItems = :totalNumberOfItems,totalItemSize = :totalItemSize WHERE courseId = :courseId")
fun update(
    totalNumberOfItems: Int,
    totalItemSize: Long,
    courseId: Int?
)
```

Here in database totalNumberOfItems is 5 but now when i update this it will replace old data instead of increment in old data.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to increment data within an entry of a  database table is to first fetch the data from the database, then execute an operation on it (in your case you probably want to **sum** it) and then update the entry using the update statement.